# RESTful API authentication/authorization on tomcat without forms

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, tomcat, authentication

Is there any way to shut off the forms when doing authentication with Tomcat?

I have a RESTful API in a webapp, without any UI whatsoever, and I want the Login Form and credentials to be provided by a different UI client via AngularJS (a different webapp).

For the server, I use web.xml to declaratively require a security-constraint, like:

```xml
  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Hello Services</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/gbs/gbooks/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>hello-role2</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
      <!--<user-data-constraint>-->
        <!--<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>-->
      <!--</user-data-constraint>-->
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>hello-role2</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method> <!-- or BASIC -->
      <realm-name>default</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

(Eventually I will add realms, https etc.) I am also using CXF for the JAXRS endpoints with SecureAnnotationsInterceptor and jsr250 `@RolesAllowed` annotations in my REST services.

If I use the login-config above with FORM or BASIC, it works, but of course I want the login form to be done by the client. If I omit the login-form, then tomcat seems to ignore the security-constraint, and no authentication is required for my endpoints.

The point is that I want a RESTful auth/auth service ONLY, where I post the credentials over https and get back a success (plus a cookie or sessionId or whatever I need here) or 401, 403 or 419 error. My client will be an AngularJS app, similar to what is described here:

[AngularJS example](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec)

Can this be done, or what would be a better way to do this?

Comment: So what is the question here?  You seem to have answered it your self.  Your do not want to use Form Auth or basic auth, and just want them to pass a security token to you that you validate.  You seem to have already figured out what you want.   What is being asked?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I had so many problems that I guess I wasn't clear. I'm new to javascript and AngularJS and frontend programming, so it's confusing as heck to figure all of this out. The jist of it was that Angular was posting json and instead I needed j_username=user and j_password=blah. So now it works. What should I read to learn how the security stuff works (eg useCredentials, cookies, tokens) and how do I figure out what is applicable? There's so much out there that it's hard to decipher what applies!  Anyway, thanks much!